# C# turning console output on/off

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I am making a C# DLL that analyzes network traffic using SharpPcap. One of the tings I want to implement is togglable console output. The idea is to have a method in my class

```
public void ConsoleOutputOn(bool outputOn)
```

that receives true if console output is desired, and false if it is not. I don't know how would I implement that.

In LUA I could write

```
local dprint2 = function() end
function consoleOutput(outputOn)
  if (outputON == true) then
    dprint2 = function(...)
      print(...)
    end
  else
    dprint2 = function() end
  end
end
```

If consoleOutput(true) was called, the dprint2 would become print, and each time dprint2 was called the input arguments would be passed to print and printed on console output. If consoleOutput(false) was called than dprint2 would be empty function that did nothing.

I tried to do the same in C#, my class would have private variable "consoleOn", and instead of print I would call

```
public void ConsoleOuptput(...) {
  if(outputOn) {
    Console.WriteLine(...);
  }
}
```

that would check if "consoleOn" is true, and if it is, send arguments to Console.WriteLine().

Problem is that Console.WriteLine() is overloaded 19 times for all kinds of input arguments. Is there even a way to code "if sonsoleOn pass all arguments to Console.WriteLine()". Or is there a better way to make toggleable Console output.

Keep in mind tha I am making DLL. I can't just turn of console completely.

Comment: If you only need to control output generated from your own code then why won't a wrapping method like `ConsoleOutput` be good enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach I've used quite successfully with this recently is to use a logger instance (probably just `TextWriter`) that *is allowed to be null*. Now, the purists might be thinking "null objects are an anti-pattern", but it allows some awesome usage, for example:

```
log?.WriteLine($"Connection from '{from}' to '{to}', {data.Length} bytes to process...");
```

which is then *basically free* if the `log` instance is `null`, thanks to the way the short-circuiting is evaluated. And of course, `Console.Out` is a `TextWriter`, so if you want to enable console logging:

```
myApp.Log = Console.Out;
```

But equally you can log to a file, or a network socket, or anything else - just by changing what you assign to `myApp.Log`. And if it is `null`: logging just stops.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is simply wrapping the `Console` with a toggable class:

```
public class MyToggableConsole
{
    public bool On { get; }
    public void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        if (!On)
           return;

        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }

    //Do same for all other `WriteLine` and `Write` overloads you need.
}
```

Or if it's very local, say one method, you can even consider defining a local `Action` based on `outputOn`:

```
var WriteToOutput = outputOn ? new Action<string>(s => Console.WriteLine(s) : new Action<string>(s => { } );
```

Comment: But doesn't that remove functionality? Newly wrapped console can now only take strings as parameters, not arguments like 
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", value1, value2, value3);

is that is so, that is not what I need. And Simpler solution for tat would be just creating a method that checks if outputOn is true and passes the string

Comment: @dantex47 hence why I included the comment; do same for all other overloads you might need. Also, if your using c# 6, with string interpolation you don't really need much more.